# KineticJs jigsaw puzzle scramble

Tags: javascript, html, random, kineticjs, scramble

I currently doing a jig-saw puzzle HTML5 Project, now i am stuck with that i want my puzzle pieces be all around the container when i start playing, anyone can help me with the start? thanks.

```
    function jigsaw(){
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "kidwallpaper.jpg";
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        drawImage(this);
    }
 }
```

P.S : This is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a random offset to each piece's x,y position.

```
x: i + pieceWidth / 4 + Math.random()*(stage.getWidth()-pieceWidth),

y: j + pieceHeight / 4 + Math.random()*(stage.getHeight()-pieceHeight),
```

Comment: Thanks :) it works, but am i able to rotate the pieces to different degree when i scramble? thanks

Comment: Oh, ok, so what should i add it in? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, your own design requirements determine how you want to do rotation. If you want to rotation around an objects center then set the rotation point (offsetX/offsetY) at the center of your object then set your rotation angle.

Comment: Thanks for the help :), so if i want my pieces to rotate 90degree, i should add something around here?                                           var offsetX=pieceWidth*i;                                           var offsetY=pieceHeight*j;